# Deploy BgInfo Utility via a GPO

Tags: group-policy, deployment

When I deploy to a client the BgInfo utility via a GPO,I am receiving the following error.

```
Error code:800A408
```

here is my script code.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject(“Wscript.Shell”)

objShell.Run “\\Server2008\deploy\bginfo\bginfo.exe 
\\Server2008\deploy\bginfo\test.bgi /NOLICPROMPT /timer:0”, 1, True
```

thanks.

Comment: Where is that error code indicated? Can you run `bginfo` from your script using the `/log` switch to capture more info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a .vbs file make sure you deploy the aplication using `cscript.exe filename.vbs` within startup scripts (.cmd file) under GPO's Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Scripts (Startup/Shutdown) -> Startup.

Also, I would add a little code to check if it's already installed like this:

```
dim filesys
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
If not filesys.FileExists("c:\program files\bginfo\somefile.txt") Then
  Set objShell = CreateObject(“Wscript.Shell”)
  objShell.Run “\\Server2008\deploy\bginfo\bginfo.exe \\Server2008\deploy\bginfo\test.bgi /NOLICPROMPT /timer:0”, 1, True
End If
```